# Showing UIImageView in MPMoviePlayer

Tags: mpmovieplayer

Can anybody help in me out of how to show a UIImageView having Image of a border to be displayed around the Video Playing in MPMoviePlayer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure your border image has a transparent background , ie all visible parts have to be transparent

```
moviePlayer.view addSubview:borderImage;
```

This will add the UIImageView over your moviePlayer.view and the transparent portion will allow for the movie to be seen